# Prevent variable from being inlined in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have encountered an issue in a stored procedure which incrementally copies data from one table to another:

```
DECLARE @StartId bigint;

SELECT @StartId = COALESCE(MAX(Id), 0) 
FROM dbo.TargetTable WITH (NOLOCK);

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (...)
   SELECT ... 
   FROM dbo.SourceTable
   WHERE Id > @StartId
```

This stored procedure hanged for more than 15 minutes and I killed it. However if I run the two parts separately,

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id), 0) 
FROM dbo.TargetTable WITH (NOLOCK);
```

it returns immediately with the head ID being, say, 100000.

Then I replaced the `@StartId` variable with 100000 in the `INSERT` statement and run it,

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (...)
   SELECT ... 
   FROM dbo.SourceTable
   WHERE Id > 100000
```

This part finishes in less than a few seconds.

It appears that in the original stored procedure, the variable `@StartId` is inlined into the `INSERT` statement resulting in a deadlock.

I am aware there might be better ways or workarounds such as storing the progress in a third table, however, my question is can I force the variable to be evaluated before entering the `INSERT` statement?

**Edit:** Since this is inside a stored procedure, I don't have the option to use GO.

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2012? there is something weird going on with SQL Server 2012 just other day saw a similar problem where assigning value to variable would take 10 mins and without the use of variable it took less than 2 seconds.

Comment: @M.Ali I've tried the same query on both SQL Server 2008 and 2012 and the results are the same.

Comment: If it's hanging for 15 minutes that gives you ample time to fire up Activity monitor and find out what the hold up is. There are three operations going on there (SELECT, INSERT, SELECT) and we don't yet know which one is the holdup. Activity monitor will tell you. In fact you've indicated that the stored proc hung, but is this all the code in the stored proc or is there more? I'm reasonably certain that SQL is not substituting your variable in the second select with your first select, though the only way to know for sure is check the query plan.

Comment: @ElectricLlama This is the entirety of the sproc. I am not sure how to do the diagnosis but I've looked at [dm_os_waiting_tasks] which doesn't have anything from this session; [dm_exec_requests] shows it's running the SELECT; [sp_WhoIsActive] shows different parts from the SELECT query (which was omitted in the question) are being run.

Comment: I've just found out the cause is not variable expression being inlined, instead, it's an issue with execution plan with regards to variables. There is already a Q/A on that and the answer works for me very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459425/sql-server-query-fast-with-literal-but-slow-with-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found out the cause is not variable expression being inlined, instead, it's an issue with execution plan with regards to variables.

There is already a Q/A on that and the answer of applying `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` works for me very well:

[SQL Server Query: Fast with Literal but Slow with Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459425/sql-server-query-fast-with-literal-but-slow-with-variable)

Comment: There's nothing marked as answered in that link. Which answer did you apply? OPTION(RECOMPILE), OPTIMISE FOR or adding an index? Perhaps you could add it to your answer here.

Answer (score -2):

this may seem very straight forward but can you put them in two different transactions... so first you do your

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION GetMax
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id), 0) FROM dbo.TargetTable WITH (NOLOCK);
GO
 INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable (...)
 SELECT ... 
  FROM dbo.SourceTable
  WHERE Id > 100000
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION GetMax;
GO
```

can you try this?