# Performance gets worse if changing date filter from string literal to date variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that i want to run on a **date range**, but the table i want to query does not have a index for dates, therefor not having the best performance.

So to test it, i joined it with a CALENDAR table (calendarid = calendarid) which does have a index on dates, and the performance got much better (from 6-7 seconds to 1-2 seconds).

But when i actually implemented in me stored procedure i did not help and still took 7 seconds, it was very interesting why.

After testing and playing around i found that if i filter with a string literal say `'05/10/2018'` the execution time goes down to 2 seconds (and thats why in the test it was fast), but if i filter on variables `@DateFrom` the time increases to 7 seconds.

And to verify it, checked the execution plan, for date string filter, it only scans one time the calendar table on the date index, and then joins the other tables. But for variables it makes two scans on the calendar table one for the primary key and second for date index, and then joins them.

**So i have 2 questions here**

1. Why is it that for variables it takes longer
2. Is there a solution to fix the performance

I added pictures of the execution plans, First for string date filter `'05/10/2018'`, Second for date variable filter `@DateFrom`

[image: Execution plan for date string <code>'05/10/2018'</code>]
[image: Execution plan for date variable<code>@DateFrom</code>]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Query: Fast with Literal but Slow with Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459425/sql-server-query-fast-with-literal-but-slow-with-variable)

Comment: Your proc is getting compiled with the literal, but not with the parameter. There's a bunch out there on plan cache's and parameter sniffing. Brent Ozar has a ton that you can read on and see tricks like setting your parameter to a local variable inside your proc, and other tricks on indexes.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks, that question had one answer that helped me i added `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@FromDate = '05/10/2018', @TODate = '05/10/2018'))`